# How to view PMD Errors?

Tags: slf4j, pmd

When running PMD in command line, I get output showing the number of violations and errors. But, I'd like to know the details of those "Errors".

I am using "pmd-bin-7.0.0-rc4" and get output similar to the below, in command line:

Processing files 100% [========] 5289/5289 (0:01:57) Violations:47300, Errors:5

I would like to know what those 5 Errors are. I tried using the --debug flag, but that just dumps a lot of trace and debug information I don't need. How can I view log output for the Errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with `--debug` you would see the errors, but you also see many other log messages.

The errors are actually so-called "processing errors". Depending on the [report format](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_report_formats.html), they are also provided in the generated report. E.g. the XML format will contain the processing errors at the end in `<error>` elements. Also the HTML format contains the processing errors.

You can select the output format with [`--format`](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_cli_reference.html#-format), e.g. `--format xml`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that Errors aren't displayed in some report formats. Particularly, I had been using --format with CSV, and the link you shared clearly states "This format only renders rule violations. Suppressed violations or errors are ignored." Switching the report format to XML now displays the Errors.